# run.sh contains activating conda environment - Calling it from bash works but crontab does not

Tags: bash, cron, conda

See my shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"
conda activate myenvironment
cd /home/user/myproject/
python main.py
```

If I call it with bash being logged in as user, it works. But then I try calling it with this cronjob:

```
01 03 * * * /home/user/myproject/run.sh
```

It gives me this error:

```
/home/user/myproject/run.sh: line 2: conda: command not found
/home/user/myproject/run.sh: line 3: conda: command not found
/home/user/myproject/run.sh: line 5: python: command not found
```

Other relevant output from the cronjob:

```
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/user>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=user>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Where are your `conda` and `python` binaries located ? Are they in `/usr/bin` or `/bin` ?

Comment: so conda is in `/home/user/miniconda3/condabin/conda`

Comment: You have `X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>`. `/home/user/miniconda3/condabin/` is not in your PATH

Comment: yes, this seems to be the solution! Will it be enough if I specify the path to the conda? when it then activates the conda, will conda have all the environment variables as I am used to?

Comment: If you use the full path in your script, it will work. Regarding the variables, it depends. How are those variables set up ? Your cron seems to be configured to run with your user, but it is using `/bin/sh`, not `bash`, so it wont use any configuration from your `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, etc ...

Comment: this is actually a good hint. I will try this solution: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94456/how-to-change-cron-shell-sh-to-bash

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66337313/schedule-python-script-with-crontab/66355572#66355572